# Working with very large dictionaries of 2D arrays in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

In one of my project I'm working with a huge number (100.000+) of 2D arrays in a `Python 3.6.8` kernel in Jupyter Notebook. These arrays are actually raw data of images with only 1 channel and their dimensions are 100x100 pixels.

I store all of them in a large dictionary, with short strings as its keys, and the arrays as its values. I need to save this dataset, and then obviously load it to work with it elsewhere. I used `pickle` for that, but searching for some alternatives. The reason is the following: Usually I need to use my laptop for work, but when I'm trying to load the already saved `.p` file with `pickle.load()`, the Notebook kernel always dies. (The saved `.p` file takes up a lot of space, 8.83 Gb.)

When I'm trying to load it on my stronger PC at home, it works 19/20 times totally fine, but on my weak laptop it actually never does, not even for smaller, ~800 Mb sized `.p` files. My question is, that are there any better options than pickle, which in my case could be useful to save and load such dictionaries?

Comment: If you don't need the whole dataset at the same time, try batching your dataset

Comment: Yes, that was my idea too, but simply doesn't seemed too elegant... I could batch a dictionary into 80 pieces of 100 Mb sized files, and then concatenate them at loading, but... I hoped to find maybe a better solution.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. If your solution doesn't require the whole dataset to be loaded into memory at the same time, you can load each batch at a time, process it and then load the next batch. You'll never need to have the whole dataset in memory